# What to do with money earned as a musician performing gigs at venues which serve alcohol?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work, alcohol

I'm a socially conscious musician. I rhyme about things that occur in society in order to bring awareness. I don't swear in my music nor do I encourage anything that is un-islamic, in my lyrics. A lot of my music has positive messages for society.

I've recently employed someone to manage my gigs and recordings. I sometimes have to perform at venues where they serve alcohol. These institutions pay me for a gig and some of that money is obviously acquired with the sale of alcohol.

What can I do with that money? Is that money considered haram for me to spend? If so, what can I do with it? Can I give it to a beggar?

I know that money earned out of interest can be used to build a toilet for a community. I don't know if I will get that amount of money to build such a structure so some realistic ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not a good thing to delete your question when it's been answered. So please don't do it .

Comment: Please note that destroying your content is not allowed. It will most likely be reversed. If you do not wish to be associated to the content any more, you can request disassociation. Flag your post for moderator attention and ask to be disassociated. Repeated acts of self-vandalism may land you in hot water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam Brother,
It is your thoughts and intentions that pleases Allah. If in your mind or heart you know that you are not doing anything haram or not permitted by Allah you have nothing to worry about. 
Allah knows your situation and your intentions very well. What you earn by your own talent which is not haram, you have every right to use it. Imagine had that been the case, what would some Muslim brothers who have gone to the West to study do, they would probably wont make any living. because one of the most common part time jobs is to work in a Restaurant and every restaurant in West sells alcohol. Does that mean they wont there.
There may be people who would contradict this answer (or even edit it), but the fact is Alaah knows each and every persons situation.
Thanks

EDIT>>

I found this very good message on this [wesbite](http://qa.sunnipath.com/issue_view.asp?HD=1&ID=367&CATE=43)

One may either give this money to those deserving of zakat (=the poor and needy), or to charities. **There is nothing wrong or dubious with accepting this money**, because the sin devolves back to the person who wrongfully engaged in the unlawful transaction and not the actual money itself.

Although **I don't completely agree with the bold words**, but the consequences of that have been covered well on the following line.

Thanks

Comment: From you words even I can make out that you believe in what you are doing and sound completely sure that it is for the right cause. Then you should probably not have any doubt in your mind whether Allah will accept it or not. 
And considering its your secondary source of income, it wouldnt matter to do some charity and help the poor. Think practically! As i said some people do not accept my opinion because it is has a practical thought to it. Considering we are talking to each other and If you agree with my thoughts you should probably accept it as an answer.

Comment: Check my edit brother!

Answer (score -2):

Salam, It is halal it is not haram because you are not the one who got money with haram activities therefore it is halal